# SVG not working within Firefox

Tags: svg

We're currently developing our new website and we've decided to use some new SVG features.

On one of our project pages we have a SVG animation that follows the paths and draws the outline then fades into the final finished image. (see images below)

Our current problem is the SVG animation that draws the outlines don't display within Firefox, The final image fades in as planned and we have tested in other browsers such as Chrome, Safari and everything works how we envisioned it.

If anyone could point us in the right direction we'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

URL - http://labs.madebyanalogue.co.uk/analogue/work/lucky-voice-app.php

```
 <figure>
                    <div class="drawings ipad">
                        <img class="illustration" src="../images/work/lucky-voice-app/lucky-voice-app_01.jpg" alt="App Icon" />
                        <svg class="line-drawing" id="ipad" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
                                <g>
                                    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1283.635,402.858
                                        c143.279,0,259.429,116.15,259.429,259.429s-116.15,259.429-259.429,259.429c-27.602,0-53.474-3.967-78.427-11.951
                                        c-0.422-0.135-1.563-0.615-1.983-0.751c-103.918-33.845-179.019-131.515-179.019-246.727
                                        C1024.206,519.008,1140.356,402.858,1283.635,402.858z"/>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1282.706,506.785
                                        c86.061,0,155.826,69.766,155.826,155.826s-69.766,155.826-155.826,155.826c-16.579,0-32.119-2.383-47.107-7.178
                                        c-0.253-0.081-0.939-0.369-1.191-0.451c-62.418-20.329-107.528-78.995-107.528-148.197
                                        C1126.88,576.551,1196.646,506.785,1282.706,506.785z"/>
                                </g>
                                <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1542.178,921.53l-518.028-0.139V402.91h518.34v468.332
                                    c0,0,0.13,51.667,0.13,51.96C1542.622,923.495,1542.178,921.53,1542.178,921.53z"/>
                                <path display="none" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1577.545,728.638
                                    c0.599-1.922,1.098-24.892,1.098-28.13c0-3.238,0.339-44.827,0.339-44.827H979.276c0,0-0.247,62.331-0.247,64.659
                                    c0,2.328,0.247,9.552,0.247,9.552l68.194-1h529.676L1577.545,728.638z"/>
                                <g id="_x31_024_1_">
                                    <g>
                                        <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1448.534,362.935h-76.694h-253.605
                                            c-74.395,0-134.703,60.312-134.703,134.705v330.295c0,74.394,60.309,134.705,134.703,134.705h330.299
                                            c74.395,0,134.703-60.312,134.703-134.705V496.64C1583.237,422.247,1522.929,362.935,1448.534,362.935L1448.534,362.935z"/>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1246.419,844.098v-71.26h-73.208v-74.207h-72.561
                                    V479.5h146.582v72.708h74.399V479.5h144.605v219.131h-71.689h-0.221c0,0-0.019,0.74-0.019,1.245s0.019,1.304,0.019,1.304v70.658
                                    h-72.695v72.26H1246.419z"/>
                                <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1542.49,402.91l-519.979,519.979c0,0-39.178-36.889-39.178-97.555
                                    V490c0,0,1.229-52.125,40.948-88.062c0,0,0.438,0.359,0.531,0.515c0.094,0.156,1.025,0.994,1.025,0.994l518.303,518.303"/>
                                <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1467.281,963.015V363.309h-73.211h-294.337
                                    v597.87l0.238,0.399C1101.867,962.177,1467.281,963.015,1467.281,963.015z"/>
                                <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1320.359,962.015V362.309h-13.681h-58.024v597.87
                                    l-0.952,0.399C1248.083,961.177,1320.359,962.015,1320.359,962.015z"/>
                                <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M984.654,700.014h599.706v-14.681V625.31H983.333
                                    L984.654,700.014z"/>
                                <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M984.142,845.448h599.706l-0.488-72.723V478.388H985.49l-0.399,0.238
                                    C984.493,480.522,984.142,845.448,984.142,845.448z"/>
                         </svg>
                    </div>
                    
                </figure>
```

[image: SVG Animation]
[image: Image load after Animation]

Comment: You need to (1) Explain what is wrong (2) Deal with one issue at a time (3) Post your code here (A live example is a useful bonus, but not a substitute for code in the question).

Comment: I'm getting the following error in FF:"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://labs.madebyanalogue.co.uk/analogue/font/gibsonsb-webfont.ttf. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Comment: The pages look the same for me in both Chrome and FF. Rather than posting the whole page, please provide a fiddle with the smallest possible snippet that demonstrates the problem.